# onDelete: 'cascade' not deleting the child rows

Tags: javascript, node.js

**This is author table**.

```
const fieldSchema = {
author_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey:true,
    autoIncrement:true
},
name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}
const tableSchema = {
tableName: 'author,
order:'author_id'
};
const Term = db.define('author', fieldSchema, tableSchema);
```

**This is book model.**

```
const fieldSchema = {
book_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey:true,
    autoIncrement:true
},
name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}
author_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
}
const tableSchema = {
tableName: 'author,
order:'author_id'
};
const Term = db.define('author', fieldSchema, tableSchema);

Book.belongsTo(Author, {foreignKey: 'author_id', targetKey: 'author_id', as: 'author', onDelete: 'cascade'});
```

when I delete one author, then the book related to that author is not deleting.
When we write onDelete:'cascade' that should work but it is not working.

Did I do anything wrong. Please help me out of this or you can suggest me another way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you have 'cascade' rules defined in your db tables. I used to have the same problem earlier and the reason was that they weren't defined in my db and I actually had to add `onDelete`, etc. to my migrations.

Comment: you mean in my **mysql** db.